# Is there a way to auto submit the form on initalization of the aura component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have an aura component bundle (let's say B) with a simple form. On submission of the form, redirects to the target URL mentioned in the action attribute.

My question is, When I invoke B from the component A, I will set the component and/ form attributes and I do not want to display component B to the user. Instead, I want form to be submitted automatically on initialization of component B.

Here is the component B:

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute access="PRIVATE" name="attribute1" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute access="PRIVATE" name="attribute2" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute access="PRIVATE" name="attribute3" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute access="PRIVATE" name="attribute4" type="String" default="1" />
    <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}"/>

        <div class="slds-m-around--medium slds-hidden">
        <div class="slds-page-header" role="banner">
            <div class="slds-media__body">
                <form  name="testForm" aura:id="viewForm" action="https://test.test123.com" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" target="_top" >    
                 <b> Attribute 1: </b><input type="text" name="inputfield1" value="{!v.attribute1}"/><br/><br/>
                 <b> Attribute 2: </b><input type="text" name="inputfield2" value="{!v.attribute2}"/><br/><br/>
                 <b> Attribute 3: </b><input type="text" name="inputfield3" value="{!v.attribute3}"/><br/><br/>
                 <b> Attribute 4: </b><input type="text" name="inputfield1" value="{!v.attribute4}"/><br/><br/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="testSubmit"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

I am looking for some suggestions to auto submit form in lightning component. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: *from the component A, I will set the component and/ form attributes* -- If you can do so from Component A, why will you even need to go to Component B then? Can you clarify exactly what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do so directly without cooperation from "B". It is not possible to  access a child component's DOM. You would instead need to modify component "B" to have an aura:method, attribute, etc to allow outside access to submit the form. For example:

```
<aura:attribute name="autoSubmit" type="Boolean" default="false" access="public" />
```

...

```
doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
  if(component.get("v.autoSubmit")) {
    component.find("viewForm").submit();
  }
}
```

Short of having a method designed to do this from within "B", "A" won't be able to automatically submit the form.